# One method to handle all the struct types that embed one common struct (json marshalling)

Tags: generics, model-view-controller, go, struct, interface

I have a gin-gonic web app with somewhat MVC architecture. I created a couple of models, all of them embed one common struct:

```golang
type User struct {
   ID int
   Name string
}

type Admin struct {
   User
   Level int
}

... {
   User
}
```

Now I want to store them in database in json format. The goal I want to accomplish is to code only one function/method that will marshal any model and will save save it into DB. This method must marshal all the fields of current model, not only from User struct, e.g. User must be marshaled into `{id: 1, name: "zhora"}`, while Admin will go into `{id: 1, name: "gena", level: 2}`.

Like this one:

```golang
func (i *User) Save() {
  data, err := json.Marshal(i)
  check(err)
  if i.ID == 0 {
    _, err = app.DB.Exec(`INSERT INTO users(data) VALUES ($1) `, string(data))
  } else {
    _, err = app.DB.Exec(`UPDATE users SET data = $1 WHERE id=$2`, string(data), i.ID)
  }
  check(err)
}
```

Right now I have to copy/paste this `func` to every model file, changing only method receiver. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use one `func Save(d interface{})` like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

type Admin struct {
    User
    Level int
}

func main() {
    Save(User{})
    Save(Admin{})
}

func Save(d interface{}) {
    body, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    st := string(body)
    fmt.Println(st)
}
```

output:

```
{"ID":0,"Name":""}
{"ID":0,"Name":"","Level":0}
```

---

for your case, use this one function for all types:

```golang
func Save(i interface{}, id int) {
    data, err := json.Marshal(i)
    check(err)
    if id == 0 {
        _, err = app.DB.Exec(`INSERT INTO users(data) VALUES ($1) `, string(data))
    } else {
        _, err = app.DB.Exec(`UPDATE users SET data = $1 WHERE id=$2`, string(data), id)
    }
    check(err)
}
```

And call it like this:

```golang
u := User{}
a := Admin{}

Save(u, u.ID)
Save(a, a.ID)
```

---

And Yes, this is even simplifies call to `Save` to one parameter:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Model interface {
    ID() int
    setID(int)
}

type User struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}

func (t User) ID() int      { return t.Id }
func (t User) setID(id int) { t.Id = id }

type Admin struct {
    User
    Level int
}

func main() {
    Save(User{})
    Save(Admin{})
}

func Save(d Model) {
    body, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    st := string(body)
    fmt.Println(st)

    fmt.Println("ID is ", d.ID())
}
```

output:

```
{"Id":0,"Name":""}
ID is  0
{"Id":0,"Name":"","Level":0}
ID is  0
```

---

Now You may use this one function for all types:

```golang
func Save(i Model) {
    data, err := json.Marshal(i)
    check(err)
    id := i.ID()
    if id == 0 {
        _, err = app.DB.Exec(`INSERT INTO users(data) VALUES ($1) `, string(data))
    } else {
        _, err = app.DB.Exec(`UPDATE users SET data = $1 WHERE id=$2`, string(data), id)
    }
    check(err)
}
```

And call it like this:

```golang
u := User{}
a := Admin{}

Save(u)
Save(a)
```

---

[Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters):

> Getters
>
> Go doesn't provide automatic support for getters and setters. There's
>   nothing wrong with providing getters and setters yourself, and it's
>   often appropriate to do so, but it's neither idiomatic nor necessary
>   to put Get into the getter's name. If you have a field called owner
>   (lower case, unexported), the getter method should be called Owner
>   (upper case, exported), not GetOwner. The use of upper-case names for
>   export provides the hook to discriminate the field from the method. A
>   setter function, if needed, will likely be called SetOwner. Both names
>   read well in practice:
>
> ```
> owner := obj.Owner()
> if owner != user {
>     obj.SetOwner(user)
> }
> ```

Comment: @kakysha I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! Very appreciate your help. Your solution works, but I went a little bit further and created an interface `Model` with `getID() int` and `setID(int)` methods, made `User` satisfy this interface and used `Model` instead of `interface{}` as parameter to method `Save(m Model)` to not pass id as second argument, only the struct itself. Also I needed it to assign ID field on passed structs after `INSERT ... RETURNING id`. Thanks again!, you saved me!

Comment: saw your update about getters and setters. Made User.ID unexported and renamed getID() to ID(), thanks again. For some reason `golint` didn't complain about it :(