# C++ Template-like behavior in Go

Tags: c++, templates, go

For example I have two different structs `Foo` and `Bar`

```
struct Foo {...}
struct Bar {...}
```

and a lot of functions and other types built on them.

C++ flavor:

```
template<typename T>
struct Identified {
    T model;
    std::string id;
};

template<typename T>
Identified<T> GetIdentifiedModel(std::string id) {
    Identified<T> result;
    T.id = id;
    T.model.set(getSomeData(id));  // Common method for T
    return result;
}
```

How to implement these examples in Go?

For common methods, interfaces do the job but I don't see how to retrieve a specific type from an interface to declare it, return it or anything else and I can't handle copy/paste code anymore :)

Thanks !

Edit @Amd: https://ideone.com/rqpsQb

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    char c;
    void set(std::string s) {c = s[0];}; // We don't really care here
};
struct Bar {
    int n;
    void set(std::string s) {n = s.size();}; // We don't really care here
};

template<typename T>
struct Identified {
    T model;
    std::string id;
};

template<typename T>
Identified<T> GetIdentifiedModel(std::string id) {
    Identified<T> result;
    result.id = id;
    // Obviously shouldn't be ID but for the example
    result.model.set(id);  // Common method for T
    return result;
}

void assert(bool b) {
    if (b) std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "There is a problem !" << std::endl;
};

int main() {
    auto fooWithID = GetIdentifiedModel<Foo>("foo id");
    auto barWithID = GetIdentifiedModel<Bar>("bar");
    assert (fooWithID.model.c == 'f');
    assert (barWithID.model.n == 3);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: the lack of generics/templates is a major criticism against golang. you can't do it, at least until google will add them

Comment: @DavidHaim: the lack of generics/templates is a major feature of golang. :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB if re-implementing each mechanism 10 times is a feature, I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You may use

```
fooWithID := GetIdentifiedModel("foo id", &Foo{})
```

like this working sample ( try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l2ffqi7V1W)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    c byte
}

func (t *Foo) set(s string) { t.c = s[0] }

type Bar struct {
    n int
}

func (t *Bar) set(s string) { t.n = len(s) }

type Identified struct {
    model T
    id    string
}

func GetIdentifiedModel(id string, t T) *Identified {
    result := &Identified{model: t}
    result.id = id
    result.model.set(id)
    return result
}

func assert(b bool) {
    if b {
        fmt.Println("OK")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("There is a problem !")
    }
}

func main() {
    fooWithID := GetIdentifiedModel("foo id", &Foo{})
    barWithID := GetIdentifiedModel("bar", &Bar{})

    assert(fooWithID.model.(*Foo).c == 'f')
    assert(barWithID.model.(*Bar).n == 3)
}

type T interface {
    set(string)
}
```

output:

```
OK
OK
```

---

2- You may use (this is nice to read: `Identified model Foo`):

```
fooWithID := GetIdentifiedModel("foo id", &Identified{model: &Foo{}})
```

like this working sample ( try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BilGn2SoNJ)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    c byte
}

func (t *Foo) set(s string) { t.c = s[0] }

type Bar struct {
    n int
}

func (t *Bar) set(s string) { t.n = len(s) }

type Identified struct {
    model T
    id    string
}

func GetIdentifiedModel(id string, result *Identified) *Identified {
    result.id = id
    result.model.set(id)
    return result
}

func assert(b bool) {
    if b {
        fmt.Println("OK")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("There is a problem !")
    }
}

func main() {
    fooWithID := GetIdentifiedModel("foo id", &Identified{model: &Foo{}})
    barWithID := GetIdentifiedModel("bar", &Identified{model: &Bar{}})    
    assert(fooWithID.model.(*Foo).c == 'f')
    assert(barWithID.model.(*Bar).n == 3)
}

type T interface {
    set(string)
}
```

output:

```
OK
OK
```

---

See also: [One method to handle all the struct types that embed one common struct (json marshalling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131886/one-method-to-handle-all-the-struct-types-that-embed-one-common-struct-json-mar)